# How to change input text color in css, while using bootsrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap and I want to change input text color to black but is not working.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="nomclient" style="background-color: white;" style="color: black;" />
```

Comment: You have duplicated `style` attribute.

Comment: i removed it and put it on css **style**   ``input { padding: 5px 10px;  color: black;
                   }``     still not working, even tho the padding is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? i tried this code and it works fine!

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="nomclient" style="background-color: white; color:black;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about CSS in general, you have duplicate `style` attribute and this is not allowed .. also read more about Bootstrap classes, you can use class `bg-white` for white background and `text-dark` for dark text.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>







<input type="text" id="name" name="nomclient" class="bg-white text-dark" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated style attribute which isn't allowed.
For your colors, you can use Bootstrap classes.

***bg-white*** = background-color: "white"

***text-dark*** = color: "black"